# stopVPNTunnel is not disconnecting the VPN connection in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, nevpnmanager

I have implemented one successful vpn connection. But When i close and Open app while the VPN is connected, then i can't disconnect the VPN.

```
public func connectVPN() {
    //For no known reason the process of saving/loading the VPN configurations fails.On the 2nd time it works
    Log.d(message:  "connectVPN")
    NSLog("ConnectVPN")
    self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnLoadHandler)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NEVPNStatusDidChange, object: nil , queue: nil) {
        notification in
        let nevpnconn = notification.object as! NEVPNConnection
        let status = nevpnconn.status
        self.vpnDelegate?.checkNES(status: status)
    }
}

public func disconnectVPN() ->Void {
    Log.d(message:  "Disconnect VPN Called")
    Log.d(message: "Log Disconnect VPN Called")
    
    print("vpnManager:disconnectVPN \(self.vpnManager.connection) ") // object available
    
    self.vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
}
```

I could not find out why it is not disconnecting.

Comment: It's a mess, but after creating new `NETunnelProviderManager` and saving it to preferences with `saveToPreferences()`, you always have to call `tunnelProvider.loadFromPreferences()`. So maybe that's why.

Comment: Can you please suggest me any resource that follows your thought? It would be very helpful. i have been stuck here for 3 days now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `stopVPNTunnel()` inside `loadFromPreferences` closure.

```
NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences { error in
  assert(error == nil, "Failed to load preferences: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
  NEVPNManager.shared().connection.stopVPNTunnel()
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! I was going nuts why this wasn't working.